# Who gets the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

The faq says:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

What if more than one answer have the same number of upvotes? Who will get half the bounty? Will it be split again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/206169)

If $\zeta(s+it)=0$ for some $s>0$ and $t\in \mathbb R$, then $s=1/2$. Don't say that this is trivial, StackExchange.

Comment: You mean to say that you don't immediately see the proof of this claim? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link and i think i never said it is trivial , did I?

Comment: @draks: 5PM's joke refers to SE's autoconversion of short-answers-with-links to comments.

Comment: Puh, that is fine then...

Comment: I have a wonderful proof of that, but unfortunately it won't fit in this comment box.